# Is it possible to reuse the input without storing it into a variable after used for a condition?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wonder is it possible to store the current `scan.nextLine()` after comparing it to a String variable without creating any new variable? Language: Java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String words = "something";

if(!scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(words)) {
     // replace words with `scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: if you immediately pass its result to a method, but then the method parameter is sort of variable. otherwise you can't.

Comment: So the ```scan.nextLine()``` will lose the data after using it in the if-statement condition in this scenario?

Comment: correct, nextLine() gives you a string, you apply equalsIgnoreCase on it, all that's left is a boolean result

Comment: Why are you trying to not store it in a variable? One of the major benefits to variables is that they're a container for information.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, another variable won't be made but when you access the method it will make a variable and store it but it will go on in the background, you won't have to make a new variable in your main class. Variable made in class don't occupy memory till an object is made out of it.

```
public class testing {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = "something";

String hello(String which_you_want_to_store) {
    which_you_want_to_store = sc.nextLine();
    if (!which_you_want_to_store.equalsIgnoreCase(this.str)) {
        this.str = which_you_want_to_store;
    }
    return which_you_want_to_store;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    testing obj = new testing();
    obj.hello(null);
    System.out.println(obj.str);

}
```

}

Comment: you string words which was intitially "something" is still stored in the string pool area.

Comment: Wait, but if I do it this way, it will asks me to input twice

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the input without storing it into a variable something like ```String temp;```?

Comment: you have to allot some memory to what you want to store and for that, you need a variable.

Comment: yes, first time for changing the string words and then comparing it to the string that you entered.

Comment: I tried another method if you find it useful select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need to write a new class, and `Scanner` is `final` = non-extendable.
It would be not a large effort though. Maybe you can use a `BufferedReader` instead.

Otherwise use an expression inside which one assigns to a single variable declared in front. The same pattern one sees with `BufferedReader`.

```
String line = "";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String words = "something";

if (!(line = scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase(words)) {
     // replace words with `scan.nextLine();
     ... line ...
}
```

Not necessarily good taste.

Comment: So I must create a variable to store a input right? Otherwise the data will lost?

Comment: yes, there is only one current token and next* consumes the current, and gives the next.